# ocultar y mostrar un div desde otra vista obteniendo valor de variable de URL

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net

Este es el código de la página Origen

```
<li class=" column list-group-item float-e-margins">
    <a href="~/Questions/Questions?valor=1">
        <span class=" label label-primary">REGISTRO</span>
    </a>
</li>                                                             
<li class=" column  list-group-item float-e-margins">
  <a href="~/Questions/Questions?valor=2">
      <span class="label label-primary">VENTA</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Y este el código de la página destino

/**
     * Funcion que captura las variables pasados por GET 
      http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/pagina.html?id=10&pos=3
     * Devuelve un array de clave=>valor
     */

```
<script>
function getGET() {
    // capturamos la url
    var loc = document.location.href;
    // si existe el interrogante
    if (loc.indexOf('?') > 0) {
        // cogemos la parte de la url que hay despues del interrogante
        var getString = loc.split('?')[1];
        // obtenemos un array con cada clave=valor
        var GET = getString.split('&');
        var get = {};




        // recorremos todo el array de valores
        for (var i = 0, l = GET.length; i < l; i++) {
            var tmp = GET[i].split('=');
            get[tmp[0]] = unescape(decodeURI(tmp[1]));
        }
        return get;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    //ocultar todos los divs
    $('#registro').hide();
    $('#compra').hide();

    // Cogemos los valores pasados por get
    var valores = getGET();
    if (valores) {
        // hacemos un bucle para pasar por cada indice del array de valores
        for (var index in valores) {
            if (valores[index] == 1) {
                $('#registro').toggle(2000);
                $('#compra').hide();
            }
            else if (valores[index] == 2) {
                $('#registro').hide();
                $('#venta').toggle(2000);
            }

        }
    } 
}
</script>




<body>
 <!--Registro-->
            <div class="card" id="registro">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link " type="button">
                            Registro
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class=" col-lg-12">
                        <ul class="list-group clear-list m-t">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <strong>RESPUESTAS</strong>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <!--Compra-->
            <div class="card" id="compra">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button id="" class="btn btn-link">
                            Compra
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class=" col-lg-12">
                        <ul class="list-group clear-list m-t">
                            <li class="list-group-item fist-item">
                                <strong>RESPUESTA</strong><br />

                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                 RESPUESTA
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </body>
```

me ayude con el codigo de http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/pagina.html?id=10&pos=3 , le modifique algunas cosas la cual era conforme a mi necesidad. Lo que realizo es que estoy en mi pagina preguntas y selecciono digamos la opcion Registro entonces me direcciona a mi pagina donde se encuentran las respuestas, pero solo quiero que me muestre las respuestas correspondientes a lo que quiero, entonces mando por el URL un valor de una variable y lo recibo en la página destino y con javascript obtendre el valor de esa variable atraves de metodos los cuales ya agregue. Espero darme a entender :).

Comment: No he entendido muy bien tu problema, por como tienes la pregunta es difícil ayudarte, si puedes mejora la explicación del problema e incluye algo de código de lo que has intentado para que sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no entiendo algunos códigos. Digamos tengo en una vista una sesion de preguntas y si yo escojo preguntas sobre la venta me mande a la vista de respuestas pero en esa vista de respuestas tengo todas las respuestas de todas las categorias a buscar, y queiro que me oculta todos los div que no hablen sobre las ventas

Comment: sin codigo es como adivinar cual es tu problema